# Update a column in a datagridview

Tags: datagridview

After editing a column, I wanted to update another column in a datagridview.

For example, I have a datagridview with columns:

DeliveryReceiptNumber   Balance   Discount  Payment  BalanceAfterPayment

2008-02-1211            1000.00   0.00      0.00     1000.00

The intended result after editing the values in the Discount and Payment columns is to subtract the value of the Payment column from the Balance column and to update the BalanceAfterPayment column with the difference.

In what datagriview event should i put the code for updating?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might just do it inline on the datagrid. otherwise i would use the ondatabound eventhandler.